# Game development graduate portfolio

Tags: web

I graduated 3 months ago as a game developer, which included classes on C#, C++ and  UI design (for games) as well as storyboarding and 3D + PBR. I have also recently started using angular for work, to make a three.js application.

The problem is, I am struggling to create a website for myself to showcase my projects, I have a few code projects (for windows/unity WebGL). And I have a general idea of how I would like my website to look. But I lack the html/css/js knowledge to get it running.

I have been looking into various options, from using a simple wix page, to a wordpress. Using bootstrap studio is something as well. But I just found Angular.

I don't really like going for the easy route, since it has its limitations, and to be honest the templates offered are pretty generic. I would like my portfolio to not be 'just another programmer portfolio' I want to make it unique.

Now here is where my question comes in. What do I use? Do I go for wix/wordpress for simplicity? Do I use bootstrap studio? Do I make it in angular? How does performance hold up and browser compatibility? Or maybe even a combination, using bootstrap with angular to make javascript and easy page layouting...

As you can tell, I have tried to find something to use, but I get stuck with different options and not really knowing much about it...

Any tips, references or comments will be greatly appreciated.

Note: I was redirected here from SO, I hope this is the right place to ask this question. If not, please tell me and I will move it to where it belongs.

Comment: Yes, this is the place to ask for software recommendations, but your question is too broad. I wouldn't know of any Stack Exchange site for this.

Comment: I don't really know how to make it less broad though. In essence I want to make my portfolio stand out, but am hardly familiar with web development... So I came to ask more experienced people to give me info on what software would fit my knowledge profile of .NET. This being said, I dont mind learning html, which is what I am doing right now anyway